# Dúvida sobre telas de um questionário (quiz)

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um APP como este da imagem abaixo. A minha dúvida é como fazer, por exemplo como podemos ver, tem 35 perguntas e é a primeira sendo respondida, nesse caso tem que tem 35 `Activity`?

Qual seria a melhor abordagem neste caso?

No meu APP, vai ter uma opção de cadastrar as perguntas, então não sei qual o número exato de perguntas que o questionário irá ter...

Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta tem muitas outras perguntas.. Mas, a grosso modo, você pode ter apenas 1 Activity de perguntas e recarregar as informações na tela.Você pode usar um contador para saber qual pergunta carregar (se forem sempre na mesma ordem). Sobre não saber quantas perguntas serão, você pode ter uma nova Activity específica para que seja realizado esse cadastro.

Answer (score 5):

Sua dúvida pode ser respondida com uma simples análise de contexto:

Faz sentido você mudar o contexto do usuário (trocar `Activity`) apenas para mudar a pergunta? Se você acha que faz sentido, então a resposta é sim, você irá precisar criar uma `Activity` para cada pergunta.

Mas, na minha opinião, não faz sentido trocar o contexto do usuário apenas para isso. Você pode tanto utilizar `Fragments`, ou atualizar a mesma `Activity`, fazendo uma animação para a próxima pergunta por exemplo.

Se sua aplicação tem todas as perguntas embarcadas no projeto (offline), você pode, por exemplo, criar um Array de Objetos e, a cada pergunta respondida, atualiza a tela com a próxima pergunta, armazenando a resposta do usuário em um Array separado.

Se por outro lado sua aplicação tem as perguntas online (vindas de um webservice/API), a cada pergunta respondida você solicita a próxima questão para o servidor e armazena a resposta do usuário, também em um Array.

Comment: Faz sentido amigão. Ja fiz um questionario antes mas acabei colocando todas as perguntas em um ListView, porém dessa maneira é nova pra mim mas vou tentar!!

Comment: @sicachester  Se ele escolhesse armazenar num Array de Objetos, essa pergunta tivesse uma imagem o que poderia ser feito.

Comment: @Rodolfo você pode criar um modelo chamado `Pergunta`, por exemplo, e ter um objeto `Bitmap` (ou qualquer outra tipagem da sua imagem) dentro do modelo. Aí é só criar um `List<Pergunta>`

Comment: @sicachester o modelo seria um layout ?.