# Como criar um modelo no Android?

Tags: java, android

A respeito sobre essa resposta [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45501/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-telas-de-um-question%C3%A1rio-quiz/45503?noredirect=1#comment233606_45503), fiz pergunta para o autor da resposta

> Se ele escolhesse armazenar num Array de Objetos, essa
>   pergunta tivesse uma imagem o que poderia ser feito.

resposta dele

> você pode criar um modelo chamado `Pergunta`, por exemplo, e ter um
>   objeto `Bitmap` (ou qualquer outra tipagem da sua imagem) dentro do
>   modelo. Aí é só criar um `List<Pergunta>`

A pergunta é o que seria esse modelo e como cria-lo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse modelo é uma classe normal, ela agrupa as informações do que você quiser, nesse caso o Bitmap por exemplo.

É basicamente a ideia de orientação a objetos.

```
public class Pergunta {

    private String nome;
    private Bitmap imagem;

    public Pergunta() {
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Bitmap getImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }

    public void setImagem(Bitmap imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }
}
```

Comment: você poderia comentar o código para entender melhor, outra esse função precisa ser completada

Comment: Rodolfo, recomendo que estude orientação a objetos... O código do Italo está simples. Ele cria uma classe chamada Pergunta e nela ele cria métodos e funções para setar ou pegar parâmetros da classe.

Comment: @Guihgo entendi agora